# How combine 2 shapeless functions (replaceAt and at) easiest way?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Maybe someone can help me with shapeless? I'm new with it.

**My concrete task** - create function that convert given tuple element into Option
For example:

```
val inp: (String, Int) = ("zzz", 5)
myfunc(inp, 1)
```

should returns: `("zzz", Option(5))`

I found that I can do these tasks with `replaceAt` and `at` functions, but I cant figure out how to do this in one generic function.
My best result is this:

```
def opt[P <: Product, U, V, R](p: P, n: Nat, u: ()=>U)(implicit at: At[P, n.N], replacer: ReplaceAt.Aux[P, n.N, Option[U], (V, R)]):R = {
  val value1: TupleOps[P] = shapeless.syntax.std.tuple.productTupleOps(p)
  val out1 = value1.at(n)
  value1.updatedAt(n, Option(u()))
}
```

So I can call it like `opt(t, 1, ()=> t.at(1))`, but I very would like to not use 3rd param

**So, in general my issue is:**

I cant combine `at()` output and `replaceAt()` input.

IDE offer me use `At[P, n.N]#Out` as `at()` output but this dont match with `U` input of `replaceAt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ModifierAt`:

```
  import shapeless.Nat
  import shapeless.ops.tuple.{At, ModifierAt}

  def myfunc[P <: Product, N <: Nat, T, P1 <: Product](p: P, n: N)(implicit
    at: At.Aux[P, N, T],
    modifier: ModifierAt.Aux[P, N, T, Option[T], (T, P1)]): P1 =
    modifier(p, Some(_))._2

  myfunc(inp, 1) //("zzz",Some(5))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is seems what I was needed in. I had trouble with `ModifierAt`, but I used `updateAtWith()` which using it. And now everything works as it should :)